# Need to parse the string separated by colon and eliminate part of the string if found the match in plsql

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I know this topic was discussed multiple times, I looked at multiple posts and answers, but could not find exactly what I need to do.

I am trying to search the string, that has multiple values of varchar2 separated by ':', and if the match is found on another string, delete part of the string that matched, and update the table with the rest of the string.

I wrote the code using combination of str and instr functions, but looking for more elegant solution using regexp, or collections.

For example, the input string looks like this: `('abc:defg:klmnp)`. Need to find for example the piece of the string (could be at any position), and remove it, that result would look like  this: `(abc:klmnp)`?

EDIT - copied from comment:
The input string (abc:defg:klmn:defgb). Let's say I am looking for defg, and only defg will have to be removed, not defgb. Now, like I mentioned before, next time around, I might be looking for the value in position 1, or the last position. So the desired part of the string to be removed might not always be wrapped in ':' from the both sides, but depending where it is in the string, either from the right, or from the left, or from both sides.

Comment: I do want lolons to be still there, exactly like I posted: ('abc:klnp). So the part of the string is removed with colons that separate that value. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of LIKE, REPLACE and TRIM functions.

```
select trim(':' from 
            replace(':'||your_column||':',':'||search_string||':',':')
           ) from table_name
 where ':'||your_column||':' like '%:'||search_string||':%';
```

Idea is,

- Surround the column with colons and use LIKE function to find the match.
- And on such matched rows, use REPLACE to replace the search string along with surrounding colons, with a single colon.
- And then use TRIM to remove the surrounding colons.

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/393bc/1)

Comment: Adding wrapping colons to the value to find even if it is first or last is neat. And then removing them at the end to clean up - great. The only thing I see is that you would need to tweak the where clause to find when it is at the start or end, as I think that only finds where it has wrapping colons already.

Comment: I have wrapped the column with colons in the where clause. `where ':'||your_column||':' like`. So, it should work even at the beginning or end.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now. Sorry, my mistake. Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (simplified) Perhaps this is what you need:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE('abc:defg:klmnop', ':defg:', ':'), '(^defg:|:defg$)', '')
     , REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE('defg:klmnop:abc', ':defg:', ':'), '(^defg:|:defg$)', '')
     , REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE('abc:klmnop:defg', ':defg:', ':'), '(^defg:|:defg$)', '')
     , REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE('abc:klmnop:defgb:defg', ':defg:', ':'), '(^defg:|:defg$)', '')
  FROM DUAL
;
```

which removes defg from start, middle, and end, and ignores defgb, giving:

- abc:klmnop
- klmnop:abc
- abc:klmnop
- abc:klmnop:defgb

And to update the table, you could:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET value = REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, ':defg:', ':'), '(^defg:|:defg$)', '')
--  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(^|.*:)defg(:.*|$)')
  WHERE value LIKE '%defg%'
;
```

(though that final regex for the where may need to be tweaked to match, hard to test...)

Comment: Thanks, but first I have to find that string. Then replace it with nothing, if it is found. What is going to happen, if the value that I was looking for was the last, and it does not have the column at the end?

Comment: And there is even bigger flaw in the logic. What is going to happen if I have values defg and defgb, but I only need to remove defg, not the other one

Comment: Let's not worry about updating the table. I can always assign the replaced value to a variable and then do the update

Comment: Okay. Let me be a bit more specific.

Comment: Okay.  AngelWarrior thanks a lot for your help and let me be a bit more specific. The input string (abc:defg:klmn:defgb). Let's say I am looking for defg, and only defg will have to be removed, not defgb. Now, like I mentioned before, next time around, I might be looking for the value in position 1, or the last position. So the desired part of the string to be removed might not always be wrapped in ':' from the both sides, but depending where it is in the string, either from the right, or from the left, or from both sides. And of course I did not see your latest comment

Comment: AngelWarrior. I cannot use 1\3, cause the number of different values in the searched string could not be identified, unless I do the loop. It would be nice, first to find matching string (exactly matching my input), then remove it from the string preserving everything else including the separator. And surely, the searched string can be anywhere in the input string.

Comment: The \1\3 was not referring to column positions, but were backreferences to the groups set by parantheses - e.g. they were the before and after the match strings. But you can ignore that one and just look at my last one which doesn't use backreferences, in order to also remove the colons correctly. The only thing the last doesn't do is that it doesn't match if the whole string is 'defg' - you'll have to consider how to handle that if it is possible.